# Open video in kodi from nautilus?

Tags: xbmc

I have kodi 16 installed on my Linux PC. I was just wondering if there was any way I could open a video file in kodi directly from a file manager(like nautilus) using the "Open With" option. Every time I have to open a video file that's not in my movie library, I have to navigate using the kodi file manager. Is there any way to add kodi to the "Open With" list?

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://askubuntu.com/questions/115591/how-can-i-remove-change-the-open-with-list

Comment: When you click on "Open With", doesn't it allow you to browse to a program of your choosing? In that case, browsing to `/usr/bin/kodi`, or wherever the program file is located, should save it in the list of available programs.